# Mac Text Editor (with function list)

Tags: macos, mac, php, text-editors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Text editor for Mac OS X](https://superuser.com/questions/55897/text-editor-for-mac-os-x)

So I've got a Mac in the post coming to me, and will probably be doing quite a bit of development on it so I am looking for a text editor (PHP + HTML mainly).

I curently use Notepad++ on Windows and I simply cannot live without the function list plugin (It displays all functions in the current PHP file in a box on the right). Do any Mac text editors have this functionality? I am fairly sure that Notepad++ isn't available on an Apple.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could try out [TextMate](http://macromates.com/) for Mac. You can download bundles for it which include all kinds of function and code shortcuts.

Comment: +1. Go To Symbol (Apple+shift+T) brings up the function list

Answer (score 4):

[TextMate](http://macromates.com/) is my editor of choice. It's slick, powerful, and very expendable with bundles.

Other to look into are [TextWrangler](http://www.barebones.com/products/textwrangler/) (free) which offers some of the same functionality, [SubEthaEdit](http://www.codingmonkeys.de/subethaedit/) which allows you to code in sync with other people, and [Coda](http://www.panic.com/coda/) which offers an "all-in-one" coding experience.

Comment: +1 for TextWrangler - also look at its more powerful sibling, BBEdit, which is not free, but of course has more features.

Answer (score 3):

[vim](http://www.vim.org/) all the way. The learning curve is quite low but you can use it on every OS and don't have to worry about changing again - ever! Editing PHP/HTML on the server will be the same across Windows, Linux and OS X.

The plugin needed for your problem is called '[taglist](http://vim-taglist.sourceforge.net/index.html)'; this is what it looks like:

[image]

Comment: I voted this up because I like the universality of using vi (or to a lesser extent, emacs) -- especially since php development often ends up being deployed to linux. However, before I clicked the up-vote arrow, I had to shield my eyes from the horror of that color scheme you're using. :-)

Comment: thats not my color scheme (i use lucius or xoria256), its the one provided by the taglist folks (check the image url) :) ... the universality of vim (and emacs) is why i always vote for vim in such "whats the best editor for xyz" ... all the textmate / notepad++ fanboys can go home, they never seem to have to edit files on servers, on other platforms etc.

Answer (score 3):

### [Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/2)

**[Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/2)** is a great replacement for notepad++ or even TextMate. I was a huge fan of TextMate but have pretty much switched to Sublime Text 2. [This article on nettuts](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/tools-and-tips/sublime-text-2-tips-and-tricks/) has some great reasons why Sublime beats TextMate. Below I added a few key things I love about it.

### Benefits:

- It is currently **FREE**!
- Actively developed
- Works on Windows, Mac & Linux
- You Can Still Use TextMate Bundles

### Awesome Shortcuts (My Favs):

- Function List: <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>
- Quick File Switching: <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>
- Find and Replace in whole folder/project: <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

php-mode in emacs has an index menu tab that will show you all functions in that file.

Answer (score 0):

[Espresso](https://espressoapp.com/) is a nifty Mac text editor for web developers.

Answer (score -1):

For something very similar to notepad++ try [Fraise](https://github.com/jfmoy/Fraise/).
If you're after a more heavyweight development tool, try [eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/), or its offshoot [aptana studio](http://www.aptana.com/).
For a more lightweight app, but still with lots of useful functions, have a look at [Komodo edit](https://www.activestate.com/products/komodo-ide/downloads/edit/).